# String trim coming out with incorrect length

Tags: java, string

I am using Java to determine the length of a double as part of a larger program. At this time the double is 666 but the length is returning as 5, which is a big problem. I read another question posted here with a solution but that didn't work for me. I will show my code and my attempt at emulating the previous solution with results.

My original code:

```
double Real = 666;
int lengthTest = String.valueOf(Real).trim().length();
System.out.println("Test: " + lengthTest);
```

This prints 5

Modifications that didn't work, and were essentially just breaking up the code into multiple lines.

```
    double Real = 666;
    String part = Real + "";
    part = part.trim();
    int newLength = part.length();
    System.out.println("new length : " + newLength);
```

This prints 5 as well.

Obviously, I want this to print how many digits I have, in this case it should show 3.

For a bigger picture if it helps I am breaking down number input into constituent parts, and making sure none of them exceed limits. ie: xx.yyezz where xx can be 5 digits, yy can be 5 digits and zz can be 2 digits. Thank you.

Comment: Did you happen to print the string to see what it looks like?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because you are using a double.

```
String.valueOf(Real); // returns 666.0, i.e. length 5
```

Try casting it to an integer first:

```
Integer simple = (int) Real;
String.valueOf(simple); // returns 666, i.e. length 3.
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize it was counting the decimal and trailing zero. I am simply subtracting 2 from the length since it will do this every time and I will always use whole numbers.

Comment: If you are always using whole numbers, then you should just use `int` in the first place, since that is just a whole number.

Answer (score 1):

A double always puts a decimal place after the number. So the number looks like 666.0. You could see this by printing `String.valueOf(Real)`. You should use an `int` instead or cast the double to an int:

```
double Real = 666;
int realInt = (int) Real;
System.out.println(String.valueOf(realInt).length());
```